# How to use quick charts with wp7?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linechart, amcharts

I'm trying to use AmCharts QuickCharts for WP7 and am failing miserably.

I've just put out a chart like this with xaml:

```
        <controls:PivotItem Header="24 hours">
            <amq:LineGraph Name="_24HoursLineGraph"></amq:LineGraph>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

What I don't know is how to transform my data so that the linegraph can interpret it and render it. I haven't found a solid tutorial on this anywhere so if you know where to find it, please point me in the direction. I'd of course rather see a nice explanation here of how to use the linechart control :)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AmCharts, but this seems like it would work on WP7 http://wpf.amcharts.com/docs/html/d9821597-1c2b-46c4-b35b-4f2fffcc3db7.htm

Comment: Thanks, no idea why I didn't find this on their page. I'll post the answer here if I solve it.

Comment: Nope, didn't work for wp7. Will continue to scavenge that site.

Comment: @Phil - Was there an error, or was nothing displayed?

Comment: Methods and properties were missing..

Comment: @Phil - This might get you started: http://blog.izzuddin.net/2011/06/using-chart-control-for-windows-phone-7/ (although it uses a column graph). You can then use the WP7 docs to change it to a line graph http://wpf.amcharts.com/quickwpdocs/

Comment: @Phil - No probs! Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to solve it although I don't like it. I'll be raising another question as to how to flexibly use this control.

```
 <amq:SerialChart x:Name="_24HoursLineGraph" DataSource="{Binding Data24}" CategoryValueMemberPath="Date"
                     AxisForeground="White"
                     PlotAreaBackground="Black"
                     GridStroke="DarkGray" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20">
        <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
            <amq:LineGraph ValueMemberPath="Close" Title="Close" Brush="Blue" />

        </amq:SerialChart.Graphs> 
    </amq:SerialChart>
```

For this to work you need to create an observable collection and bind the entire pivot control's datacontext to that observable collection. CategoryValueMemberPath will look at one axis of the object and ValueMemberPath of the linegraph will look at another dimension of the object.

[See this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6346683/264557)