# linegraph on wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, charts, amcharts

I'm using amCharts and their SerialChart combined with a LineGraph. I've gotten it to work this way:

```
 <amq:SerialChart x:Name="_24HoursLineGraph" DataSource="{Binding Data}" CategoryValueMemberPath="Date"
                     AxisForeground="White"
                     PlotAreaBackground="Black"
                     GridStroke="DarkGray" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20">
        <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
            <amq:LineGraph ValueMemberPath="Close" Title="Close" Brush="Blue" />

        </amq:SerialChart.Graphs> 
    </amq:SerialChart>
```

Code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<Currency> Data { get { return _data; } }

    private ObservableCollection<Currency> _data = new ObservableCollection<Currency>(){};

void SetContext(Item[] itemArray)
{
    _data = new ObservableCollection<Item>();    
                foreach (var item in itemArray)
                {
                    _data.Add(item);
                }
                _data.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date);

                this.DataContext = this;
}
```

I don't understand how I can target the datacontext of the linegraph instead of setting the datacontext of the entire pivot? I have three graphs in three different pivot items and I need to set the datacontext of them individually. So instead I want to do something like:

```
_24HoursLineGraph.DataContext = theDataContext;
```

But this doesn't work. I've also tried to access the linegraph itself with _24HoursLineGraph.Graphs[0].DataContext but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Charts is designed for simple scenarios with only one data source for multiple graphs. Using completely separate data sources for each graph is not supported in Quick Charts.

In your case you will need to merge all your data sources into one and then set ValueMemberPath on each graph to a respective property name in your data.

Comment: Funny thing is, I had an epiphany a little while ago where I realized that I should do just this. Then I log in and see you beat me to it :)